# SAS: getting values from select into sas variable

Tags: sas

Could you please help me to get values by select query into SAS variable.

The select always returns two data-values from table; I would like to insert them into two variables on data-step.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'select request' you mean an SQL statement, the best way to do this is probably to use "select into" syntax, which will put the variables into SAS macro varaibles.

To give an example of how this works, you may have:

```
/*test data*/
data test;
input mynumber;
datalines;
1
2
;

/*Put the data from the test dataset into two macro variables*/
proc sql;
select * 
into :mymacrovar1-:mymacrovar2
from test;
quit;

/*Retrieve the macro variables*/
data test2;
retrievevariables = &mymacrovar1;
output;
retrievevariables = &mymacrovar2;
output;
run;
```